# SSD Does Not Show In Boot Priority List

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

So I got a new SSD and cloned my old hard drive onto it, I am able to boot Windows 10 from the SSD, that all is working fine.

However, everytime I turn on my computer I have to press f11 and go to the boot menu and manually select the SSD, because I am not able to set it to first in the boot priority settings. The SSD itself shows up but with no Windows Boot Manager and so it will not boot from it. This is strange because in the f11 boot menu it DOES show up with Windows Boot Manager. I have tried swapping the SATA ports of the two drives around and that hasn't helped. The SSD does not have UEFI in the label like the HDD does, I think this may be something to do with it? I have looked in threads asking similar questions to this and I have not found my answer.

I am using the MSI Z370 Gaming M5 motherboard and Samsung 850 EVO SSD. If you need more info I will try to provide. Thankyou.

EDIT: I have read that removing the OS off the old hard drive will solve my issue. Is this definitely true? Because I can easily do that.

Comment: 1) How did you clone the disk's contents? 2) Do they have exactly the same partitions and their types, partition table type, etc.? 3) Are both SSDs using the same kind of connection (SATA/AHCI vs M.2/NVMe)?

Comment: @grawity
I cloned it using the program Macrium Reflect. They do have the same partitions (although the main OS partitions are different sizes because the drives are different sizes.) and are both GPT. They are not both SSDs, one is a HDD but they are both connected with SATA cables.

Comment: Can you make a photo of the F11 boot menu? (And since I don't know a good partitioning tool for Windows, I would boot up a Linux liveUSB and run `fdisk -l` or `gdisk -l` to make sure the partition types also match, i.e. that the EFI system partition actually still has the "EFI system partition" type and that Reflect didn't stick a generic "Basic data" type on it...)

Comment: @grawity Hahaha I'm a bit stupid. When I went to take a screenshot of the BIOS, I stumbled across a menu I hadn't seen before and I managed to successfully change the boot priority!  So problem solved. Still thanks for taking the time to help me!